# Saving a Power Platform Solution to an Azure Repo Produces No Files in Repo

Tags: azure-devops, power-platform

Using Power Platform Build Tools v2.0.7.
Following and adjusting (slightly) based on various posts and articles produces a successful Pipeline run, but does not put files into the branch. I believe the issue is within the Command Line Script, but can't identify what it might be. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

[Pipeline flow with Command Line Script displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXJke.png)

[Save and Queue Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH6fZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary to  to perform Git checkout before exporting solution :

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=22/40/z330.png

It is also possible to use Publish artifacts component :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the solution for me was to add:

```
HEAD:main
```

to the end of the `git push` command, as in:

```
git push https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{organization}/Twilio/_git/VCKeywordHandler HEAD:main
```

After that all of the folders and files showed up in the repo.